# How to create new kibana 4.1 dashboard from existing kibana 3 dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

Before now, when we import all our logs into logstash, we add some extra tags for ease of query. I was able to create a dedicated dashboard as this [one](http://snag.gy/cGDtT.jpg)

But now I have upgraded Kibana, ES and Logstash to latest version but the kibana dashboard had totally changed.

I was wondering how easy can I replicate the queries as seen in the diagram to display the data needed based on the search criteria in Kibana 4.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to get a dashboard close to it by copying each queries into the search field and saving it first.

Then in Dashboard screen, click the + sign and click on search and add each saved search queries.